# Как запустить текст в поиск os

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет мне нужна помощь, моя программа должна запускать любой файл с пк, однако она просто не может запустится из-а того что команда `def lol(): os.startfile(txt)` как то не так работает, можете ли вы мне помочь

```py
from tkinter import *
import os
window = Tk()
window.title("lol")
window.geometry('400x250')
def lol():
  os.startfile(txt)



lbl = Label(window, text="Введите путь")
lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)
txt = Entry(window, width=15)
txt.grid(column=1, row=1)
txt.focus()
btn = Button(window, text="войти", command = lol)
btn.grid(column=2, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `txt = Entry(window, width=15)` и `os.startfile(txt)`? Уверены, что `os.startfile` умеет работать с виджетом `Tk`? Если есть ошибки, то добавляйте их в вопрос

Comment: "как-то не так" это как?

Comment: ну в общем я сам этот файл перестает работать когда этот код в нем присутствует

Answer (score 0):

Код не совсем верный, есть упущения, сравните пожалуйста для анализа:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("lol")
window.geometry('400x250')
def lol():
    os.startfile('text.txt', 'edit')



lbl = tk.Label(window, text="Введите путь")
lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)
txt = tk.Entry(window, width=15)

txt.grid(column=1, row=1)
txt.focus()
btn = tk.Button(window, text="войти", command = lol)
btn.grid(column=2, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Обратите внимание, что файл в данном случае text.txt должен присутствовать